# Prerender.io first hit missed

Tags: ember.js, prerender

I installed prerender.io with Nginx on my Ember.js project.I use the Facebook debugger to check if the prerender is installed correctly. The problem:

**Each first hit of the prerender is a fail**. Unfortunately, Facebook caches this version, so it is the one that is displayed on the site.

When I ask "Fetch new scrape informations", I get a hit and the content is displayed properly.

How can I make the first try a hit?

### GUESSES

Maybe there is a problem with `window.prerenderReady`, that is used in my project ([ember-prerender](https://github.com/zipfworks/ember-prerender))?

Maybe the Nginx configuration does not wait for the result of the caching, or the caching is too long?

### INFOS

I use Nginx with the [standard configuration](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802) recommended by prerender.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook can timeout if the response takes longer than 5 seconds. It sounds like your pages are taking 5+ seconds to render when being rendered on the fly. The reason it works the second time is because the page is cached at that point and returned in < 100ms.

I'd suggest trying to speed up your page loading time so that pages rendered on the fly are returned more quickly. Send and email to support@prerender.io if you want some help there! We can send you the timings of requests being made on your URLs.